# Merging lines on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, merge, uuid

i have two tables , Primary_table_id (uuid)
where i use uuid() to generate key. another table where the key is int. i want to merge all the lines where name1 contains name 2, and the other lines which dont correspond will simply merge by changing their key using UUID(), adding null to columns with no values.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivBxE.png)

Comment: Please paste that text from the image into the question.

Comment: looks like is not possible there is not shared keys between the tables...

Comment: name2 is name1 abbreviated, both are unique in each table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the Problem using the function instring.
instr(`primary_table`.name1 ,'secondary_table'.name2)>0